# jQuery.noConflict(); with mootools

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, joomla

I want to use [this select](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfevM/100/) UI for my joomla site

i changed the original code like bellow

**changed code**

```
$(function() {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery( "#selectable" ).bind("mousedown", function(event, ui) {
        var result =  jQuery( "#select-result" ).empty();
        event.ctrlKey = true;
    });
    jQuery( "#selectable" ).selectable();

});
```

**original code**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).bind("mousedown", function(event, ui) {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        event.ctrlKey = true;
    });
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();

});
```

But it's not working with [my site](http://bluewingholidays.com/index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&id=9%3aholiday-home-in-mirissa#ad-image-4)

WHAT IS THE ERROR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the noConflict statement wrong it should be like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#selectable" ).bind("mousedown", function(event, ui) {
    var result =  jQuery( "#select-result" ).empty();
    event.ctrlKey = true;
});
jQuery( "#selectable" ).selectable();

});
```

you can even make it easier for yourself by doing this:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(function($) {
     $( "#selectable" ).bind("mousedown", function(event, ui) {
         var result =  $( "#select-result" ).empty();
         event.ctrlKey = true;
     });
     $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
});
```

Comment: http://bluewingholidays.com/index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&id=9:holiday-home-in-mirissa#ad-image-4

Answer (score 0):

You should have something along the lines of, don't need to worry about $.

Also you should load jQuery before mootools.

//edit
Check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
(function($) {
    $( "#selectable" ).bind("mousedown", function(event, ui) {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        event.ctrlKey = true;
    });
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: no it isn't working http://bluewingholidays.com/index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&id=9:holiday-home-in-mirissa#ad-image-4

Comment: (function($) {
    $( "#selectable" ).bind("mousedown", function(event, ui) {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        event.ctrlKey = true;
    });
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();

})(jQuery);

Comment: 1. you're using multiple versions of jQuery. 2 you need to use `jQuery.noConflict);` in the first `<script>` block.